# Why holds $\int_{-t}^t\omega_{n+1}(x)\text{ dx}=-\int_{-t}^t\omega_{n+1}(t-x)\text{ dx}$ for the Newton basis polynomials $\omega_{n+1}(x)$

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

Let $$\omega_{n+1}(x):=\prod_{k=0}^n(x-x_k)$$
denote the [Newton basis polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) and $$x_k:=kh-t\;,\;\;\;h:=2\frac{t}{n}$$

Why holds $$\int_{-t}^t\omega_{n+1}(x)\text{ dx}=-\int_{-t}^t\omega_{n+1}(t-x)\text{ dx}$$
for $t>0$?

Comment: Do you have a typo somewhere, or is there specific information missing about $x_0,\dots,x_n$? This statement doesn't seem to hold, in general

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - I'm sorry, I've missed out the definition of $x_k$.

Comment: Are you sure there still isn't a typo?  I checked this for $t = 1,n=2$ and this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So equivalently, we have 
$$x_k = \left(\frac{2k}{n}-1\right)t$$ 
for some positive integer $n$, $k=0,\dots,n$ and $t >0$.

Potentially helpful observation:

Note that 
$$
\omega_{n+1}(x) = \prod_{k=0}^n\left(x-\left(\frac{2k}{n}-1\right)t\right)\\
\omega_{n+1}(t-x) = \prod_{k=0}^n\left((t-x)-\left(\frac{2k}{n}-1\right)t\right)
= \prod_{k=0}^n\left(-x-\left(\frac{2k}{n}-2\right)t\right)
$$

The sum of these two is not generally an odd function, so that's not the trick.  Perhaps there is some sort of integration by parts trick here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was on the wrong path. I've decided to ask a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644282/accuracy-of-the-newton-cotes-formulas-for-polynomials-of-degree-n1-and-even